# How to determine the type of reference of ME?

Tags: vb.net

**Question:**

In the below code, The O/P of Me.testShadow() when `d.UseMe()` gets executed, in my opinion should be "Shadowing Procedure: From the Derived Class". But instead the O/P that I am getting is "From Base Class: Shadowing procedure in derived class". I present my understanding as to why I think that the former should be output. PLease tell me where I am going wrong.

1. d is the derived class type reference pointing to an object of derived type.
2. d.UseMe() executes the statement Me.testShadow() inside it. ME behaves like an object variable pointing to the current instance, that is the object pointed to by "d". Therefore the reference that ME has is of derived class type.
3. testShadow() has two versions, one in the base class and  the shadowing version in the derived class.
4. Since SHADOWS works on reference and since the type of ME reference is derived class type, I was expecting that the shadowing function in the derived class would be called? Instead, the testShadow() in the base class is being called.

Where am I mistaken? The code I wrote is given below:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim b As New base()
        Dim d As New derived()
        d.useMe()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class base
    Public Overridable Function testOverride() As String
        Return "Overrideable function: From the base Class"
    End Function
    Public Function testShadow() As String
        Return "From Base class. Shadowing function in inherited class"
    End Function
    Public Sub useMe()
        Console.WriteLine("Me.testOverride() returns: {0}", Me.testOverride())
        Console.WriteLine("Me.testShadow() returns: {0}", Me.testShadow)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class derived : Inherits base
    Public Overrides Function testOverride() As String
        Return "Overriden procedure: From derived class"
    End Function
    Public Shadows Function testShadow() As String
        Return "Shadowing procedure: From derived class"
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Me refers to the class where the code is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding follows the type of the object, while shadowing follows the type of the reference. That `useMe` method is in the base class and `Me` will always be the type of the class it's used in, so `Me` is the base type. That means that `Me.testShadow` will execute the method in the base class.

You can easily prove to yourself that `Me` is type `base` by considering the fact that it is in a base class that could be inherited in any number of derived types. How could the type of the `Me` reference change depending on the derived type on which you called that method? References don't change type at run time. They are always whatever type they were when the code was compiled. That `useMe` method was written in the `base` class so it is type `base` and will always be that type.